# Can I use the breadcrumb for the payment process like the progress bar design?

Tags: website-design, progress-bar, payment, breadcrumbs

I wonder that whether the breadcrumb model can match to the steps of payment process like progress bar model. My design in the development process, I have delivered my files to developer who's doing backend for my design. If I asked him to change HTML DOM overall, I worry he will be frustrated if repeat their code.

I need the right answer to make sure what I did it's correct according to ux/ui design.

Attached screenshot 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're asking if you can use the breadcrumb model/pattern for a payment/checkout process? It would be nice if you could show your designs or at least link to what you have in mind.

Strictly speaking, Breadcrumbs wouldn't be suitable to a checkout process (think Amazon checkout) since Breadcrumbs only display your history, not the full process. Unless you plan to adapt the breadcrumb pattern in a way this vital information will not be displayed at all.

One thing that *might* be beneficial is to add links to the steps of the payment process visualization at the top so a user can jump back to correct input, but note that I wrote "might" not "will". You probably have to see if more users exit the process or correct their payment details in a way that's hurting your business first.

Comment: Yes, that's right the breadcrumb pattern, I just attached the screen shot of my design which actually I did. Sorry for the link it's not available at the moment, It's still in stagging process.

Comment: In the design you showed I don't think that Breadcrumbs make sense. Breadcrumbs display history or site structure, neither of which is what you are describing here (a flow/process). This doesn't mean that the way it is displayed now is bad, just that I wouldn't follow the breadcrumb pattern/model.

Comment: Let me think and discuss with my patners to get make a last decision, thanks for your useful advice.